# Background Video Playlist

Tags: javascript, html, video, playlist

I have a video background setup from this tutorial: https://slicejack.com/video-background-playlist/.
I can't get the playlist to work. Can anyone help me?
There are two videos on the playlist to play but only the first one does. 
All the videos are hosted on github.
I have the setup on codepen: https://codepen.io/SEGACD32XMODEL1/pen/xxbwRdB?editors=1000

```
<div id="video-player" class="fullscreen-bg">
<video class="fullscreen-bg__video" autoplay muted poster="img/BLUE_DOTS.jpg" preload>
    <source src="https://robocop79.github.io/video/I Got a Boner! - Spongebob.mp4" 
type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="fullscreen-bg__playlist">
    <a href="https://robocop79.github.io/video/I Got a Boner! - Spongebob.mp4" class="current- 
video"></a>
    <a href="https://robocop79github.io/video/ps2rsod.mp4"></a>
    <a href="video/RED_DOTS.mp4"></a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    ( function() {
        /* Variables */
        var videoPlayer = document.getElementById( 'video-player' ),
            video = videoPlayer.getElementsByClassName( 'fullscreen-bg__video' )[0],
            playlist = videoPlayer.getElementsByClassName( 'fullscreen-bg__playlist' )[0],
            source = video.getElementsByTagName( 'source' ),
            linkList = [],
            videoDirectory = '/video/',
            currentVideo = 0,
            allLinks = playlist.children,
            linkNumber = allLinks.length,
            i, filename;

        /**
         * Load and play video
         * @param  int index Video index
         */
        function playVideo( index ) {
            allLinks[index].classList.add( 'current-video' );
            currentVideo = index;

            source[2].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.ogv';
            source[1].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.webm';
            source[0].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.mp4';

            video.load();
            video.play();
        }

        // Save all video sources from playlist
        for ( i = 0; i < linkNumber; i++ ) {
            filename = allLinks[i].href;
            linkList[i] = filename.match( /([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/ )[0];
        }

        /**
         * Play next video
         */
        video.addEventListener( 'ended', function () {
            allLinks[currentVideo].classList.remove( 'current-video' );

            nextVideo = currentVideo + 1;
            if ( nextVideo >= linkNumber ) {
                nextVideo = 0;
            }

            playVideo( nextVideo );
        } );

    } () );
</script>

<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #fff;
}

.content {
margin: 20px auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 960px;
padding: 30px 40px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

h1 {
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
}

p {
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 1.4;
}

p:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.fullscreen-bg__playlist {
display: none;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
}
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('../img/BLUE_DOTS.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

add these under video tag

```
  <source src="https://robocop79.github.io/video/I Got a Boner! - Spongebob.mp4" 
      type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://robocop79.github.io/video/I Got a Boner! - Spongebob.ogv" 
      type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://robocop79.github.io/video/I Got a Boner! - Spongebob.webm" 
      type="video/mp4">
```

---

or keep this one only in the js code

```
source[0].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.mp4';
```

Comment: by the way it means you have three sources with different extensions to the same video and the browser will choose the supported one from them

Comment: Both videos are mp4

Comment: ok then you need to remove this part source[2].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.ogv';
            source[1].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.webm';
            source[0].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.mp4';
 and only keep this  source[0].src = videoDirectory + linkList[index] + '.mp4';

Comment: Just a white screen now after the first video finishes

Comment: are you sure about the links? cuz they arent working with me